# 'Add Friend' button gone, then appeared again

Tags: facebook

I sent a friend request to someone ages ago. When I checked his profile a few days later, the 'Add Friend' button was gone. However, it's now been ages and I checked his profile again and it has appeared again.

I am guessing the button was gone because he refused my request. Does the button appearing again mean that person has unblocked me or something? Or is it something done automatically by Facebook? Also, if it's the latter, does anyone know the exact length of time needed for the button to reappear?

Answer (score -1):

**None of your assumptions are correct.**

This individual has probably changed their privacy settings in the following manner

```
- Click from the top right of any Facebook page and choose Settings
- Click Privacy in the left column
- Click Edit next to Who can send you friend requests?
- Choose an audience from the dropdown menu
```

If you were not within this audience, the "add friend" button would disappear for you.

He probably changed his settings to something which excluded you, and then a few days later changed it back again.